# Is there a way to create a Stamp annotation using a SVG as ImageData

Tags: svg, uri, pdftron

I would like to create a custom stamp annotation using a SVG in PDFTron.

I saw someone on some google forum having the same question, and a PDFTron developer actually responded, and this is what I have so far...

```
const svgElement = '<svg>my svg</svg>'

const CustomStamp = function() {
   Annotations.StampAnnotation.call(this);
   this.ImageData = encodeURI('data:image/svg+xml,' + svgElement);
}

CustomStamp.prototype = new Annotations.StampAnnotation();

const CustomCreateTool = function(docViewer) {
            Tools.GenericAnnotationCreateTool.call(this, docViewer, CustomStamp);
        };

CustomCreateTool.prototype = new Tools.GenericAnnotationCreateTool();

CustomCreateTool.prototype.mouseLeftDown = function() {
            Tools.AnnotationSelectTool.prototype.mouseLeftDown.apply(this, arguments);
        };

CustomCreateTool.prototype.mouseMove = function() {
            Tools.AnnotationSelectTool.prototype.mouseMove.apply(this, arguments);
        };

CustomCreateTool.prototype.mouseLeftUp = function(e) {
            var annotation;
            Tools.GenericAnnotationCreateTool.prototype.mouseLeftDown.call(this, e);
            if (this.annotation) {
              this.annotation.Width = 50;
              this.annotation.Height = 50;
              this.annotation.X -= this.annotation.Width/2;
              this.annotation.Y -= this.annotation.Height/2;
              this.annotation.NoResize = true;
              annotation = this.annotation;
            }
            Tools.GenericAnnotationCreateTool.prototype.mouseLeftUp.call(this, e);
            if (annotation) {
              annotManager.redrawAnnotation(annotation);
            }
```

However, it seems that it only draws an empty box... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your code and it seems correct. Trying it out myself I believe the issue is with your test SVG; it appears that by missing the `xmlns` tag it results in an invalid HTMLImage element when calling `encodeURI`.

Can you try your code with the following SVG? I used it for debugging and the stamp works as expected.

```
const svgElement = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /></svg>'
```

Comment: Hi Armando, thank you so much for your answer! Indeed, it seems that it was a problem with my SVGs, however I don't seems to understand why... I'm using SVGs from FontAwesome, and that seems to be the issue.

Also, is there a way to make it so that the color of the stamp/SVG adapts to the color that the user choses in the toolbox?

Comment: (edit) I have found the problem, it seems that it was because I didn't have a width and a height property in my SVG, so it didn't work... Now I just need to figure out how to make it so that the SVG takes the appropriate color or filling... Thank you so much Armando!